# How to remove GMT +530 from datetime column of kendo grid in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo grid and there are some editable columns. I edit `EXPECTED_DOSING` column to **26-10-2018 20:30** but when i try to get whole grid data in jquery this `EXPECTED_DOSING` column shows data like **Fri Oct 26 2018 20:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** and when i convert it into `JSON.stringify` it show me like **2018-10-26T15:00:00.000Z**. At the end a time will change from actual time. Please help me to set this.

Note: I Get Whole Grid Data not a single data.
and this is how i get grid data.

```
$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
```

Here grid is my kendo grid name.

Comment: Both date/times seem same, how do you mean it will change?

Comment: @skobaljic i pass 26-10-2018 20:30 and after convert in json.stringify i get 2018-10-26T15:00:00.000Z.here time change 20:30 to 15:00:00.000Z

Comment: Both are same, 1st one is local time, second is UTC, 15:00 UTC + 5:30 (india) = 20:30

Comment: ok ,i understand but when i pass this on server side means (view to controller) this date will reamin 15:00,it will not add UTC +5:30. @skobaljic

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI Datepicker uses JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object internally to hold the selected date value. Thus, dates are always created with the browser's offset. In order to overcome this behavior, process the date and offset it before setting the value of the DatePicker widget.

Here is a sample on how this could be achieved:

http://dojo.telerik.com/eXOgemoW